# Setting the Cursor property in Silverlight has no effect

Tags: silverlight, cursor

I'm trying to set the cursor so it changes to a hand when the mouse hovers the item.
It doesn't seem to have any effect, the cursor remains the default one.
Example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Black" Cursor="Arrow" />
</Grid>
```

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question, but...Arrow is basically the default cursor.  Did you try this with other cursors like "Hand" or "Wait"?

Comment: Big oops! I meant to change it to Arrow but wrote Hand instead. I should really get some sleep... Thanks and sorry for the stupid question.